# cannot import androidx.activity:activity:1.7.0-beta02

Tags: android

I want to support the official photo picker on older devices.
So I followed the official documentation and tried to import.

Here is my App module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aiden.mydemo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.7.0-beta02"
}
```

and my project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

But in the end, an error will be reported, and I have tried many methods and cannot solve it

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'activity.aar (androidx.activity:activity:1.7.0-beta02)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'activity.aar (androidx.activity:activity:1.7.0-beta02)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'activity.aar (androidx.activity:activity:1.7.0-beta02)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}.
```

I have tried that if the version is relatively low, such as 1.3.0, it can be added successfully, but once the version is increased, an error will be reported